# Reducing a 3/4" Male Flare to a 1/2" Male Flare

Tags: plumbing, leak, pipe, appliances, connectors

I currently have 1/2" hose and female flare fittings that I need to connect to a larger 3/4" flare. I went to a local plumbing supply store and the set of parts they gave me seems a little excessive and over-complicated (see pics below)-- most importantly it's more prone to leaks.

Is there a better way to go about this? I feel like there has to be some kind of "3/4" to 1/2" reducing adapter".

[image: side]
[image: front]
[image: diagonal]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None that I could locate. The supply store showed you the correct fittings to use. Regarding the connections not sealing properly: use Teflon tape (wrapped in the correct direction) and paste on only the pipe threads. The flared connections do not need tape or paste. It is easier to get a positive tight seal if you use either two pipe wrenches (oriented with the jaws facing each other) or set the fittings in a bench vise and than use a pipe wrench or adjustable wrench (Channel Lock pliers). You should tighten the fittings at least 3-4 full rotations (depending on the thread cut) or until you've applied a moderate amount of force. Be alert when tightening, as to much force (thanks Tester101) can crack or break the fitting. Try not to bottom out any fittings which could compromise and weaken the connection (especially be cautious with the flared fittings as to much force will flatten and distort the shape of the flared part.

Comment: thanks ojait. would this work? if not, why not? http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001JYZ2RW

Comment: The fitting from the link you posted would work , but it must be the correct size. The link showed a 3/8 inch x 1/4 inch fitting.

Comment: If you have access to a flaring tool  http://www.amazon.com/FLARING-TOOL-ADAPTOR-7-16IN/dp/B001GS1130/ref=sr_1_12?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1447357385&sr=1-12&keywords=flaring+tool&pebp=1447357398151&perid=0KFJGV5MV7245JDYZKZ4  and 2 flare nuts (1/2" and 3/4")  than get a length of copper tubing, you could bypass all the threaded fittings and make a custom flared adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the 3/4" flare x 1/2" NPT hex nipple, round backwards. The flare end should go in the swivel nut on the far right of the first photo, while the National Pipe Thread (NPT) end should go in the coupler between the two flare hex nipples.

From left to right, it should go 1/2" flare x 1/2" NPT hex nipple -> 1/2" NPT coupler -> 1/2" NPT x 3/4" flare hex nipple -> 3/4" flare swivel nut.

To do this in one fitting, you'd need a 1/2" flare x 3/4" flare hex nipple. But I don't think they make those.

Just make sure you use pipe dope on the NPT threads, you tighten all the connection enough but not too much, and you pressure test all the connections.

Comment: Is this an appropriate 1/2" flare x 3/4" flare hex nipple? http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001JYZ2RW

Comment: @kwikness Those are 1/2" male flare x 3/4" female NPT. So you'd still need something to go from 3/4" male NPT to 3/4" flare.